# How to choose all TextBoxes with foreach?

Tags: c#

I am trying to clear all TextBoxes when I click button update with foreach loop but it didn't work. but when I try to clear each TextBoxes by names it works.

```
 foreach (TextBox item in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) 
 {
     ((TextBox)item).Text = " ";
 }
```

or

```
 foreach (Control item in this.Controls) 
 {
     if (item is TextBox) {
         ((TextBox)item).Text = " ";
 }
```

Comment: Are `TextBox`s which you want to clear are on *form* or on some kind of *container*, say `Panel`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yeah its in the panel, is it different for panels?

Comment: @Daniyar Serikov: `foreach (TextBox item in MyPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) {...}` - you should scan the panel then

Comment: you need to know where they are, you are just skimming the outer level of controls.  the text boxes are probably nested inside another control.  A control can have Children or inner controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put

```
this.Controls()
```

you get `Control`s which are explicitly on `this` (form) *only*. It seems that `TextBox`es you want to clear are placed in *containers* 
(`Panel`s, `Groupbox`es etc.) so you should enumerate them:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> AllControls<T>(Control parent) 
  where T : Control {

  if (null == parent)
    yield break;

  if (parent is T control)
    yield return control;

  foreach (Control item in parent.Controls)
    foreach (T ctrl in AllControls<T>(item))
      yield return ctrl;
}
```

Then it's easy to clear them:

```
foreach(TextBox textBox in AllControls<TextBox>(this))
  textBox.Text = "";
```